# how to use (from itertools import chain) to search multiple model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i want to search field of a multiple model in a single search view here is what i tried i know this is not a clean and better way to do that's why i am looking for a clean and better way to do it i read it is possible with (from itertools import chain) but i did not completely understand how to use it in my function based views without passing so many context here is my view

```
def search_item(request):
    search_item = request.GET.get('search')
    if search_item:
        story = Story.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_item)|Q(written_by__icontains=search_item))
        news = News.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_item)|Q(written_by__icontains=search_item))
        Stock = stock.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_item)|Q(written_by__icontains=search_item))
    return render(request, 'search_result.html', {'ttts':ttt,'story':story,'news':news,'stock':Stock,})
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `itertools.chain`.

```
def search_item(request):
    results = []
    search_item = request.GET.get("search")

    if search_item:
        q = Q(title__icontains=search_item) | Q(written_by__icontains=search_item)
        for model in (Story, News, Stock):
            results.extend(model.objects.filter(q))

    return render(request, "search_result.html", {"results": results})
```

would be a simple, DRY way to write what you have.

Comment: that's intresting i didn't know this way thank you so much

Comment: but i want to ask one more thing every model has a different detail view an i want to give href for detail view of that search result how i can achieve that

Comment: Look into the `get_absolute_url` convention Django models have.